# Chromecast app is not working with my application ID

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, app-id

- Registered application in Google Cast SDK Developer Console
- Published it
- Used given application id in https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

Now I'm getting status `Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}` in `Cast.CastApi.launchApplication` callback. The app is working fine if used its own application id.
What can be wrong with my application id?

Comment: Are you using a custom receiver or a styled receiver? Have you rebooted your cast device to make sure it has the latest configuration?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I use custom receiver. Rebooted Chromecast device several times. App configuration: http://prntscr.com/ap9hvw, http://prntscr.com/ap9i8m. Earlier I also specified Android app package name, then removed it, nothing changed.

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems you are defining your receiver's url as https://ya.ru/, is that right? That doesn't seem to point to a receiver html file. Fix that and see if it starts working or not.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I've changed url to https://8sph.blob.core.windows.net/media/x.html. It is static html served by https, but I still have the same error. Are there any other requirements to it? As I understood from the documentation it's just a url to show while translation is loading.

Comment: Make sure you have rebooted your device after changing the url. What do you see on the TV screen? Does it load your page and you get a timeout in your Android or nothing happens on the TV screen?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Rebooted device. Html is loading and displayed on TV screen, then timeout happens and in some time Chromecast starts to show screensaver images.

Comment: Your page is a static page and doesn't have the receiver SDK to communicate with the sender SDK so it times out. I suggest you use a Styled receiver.

Comment: @AliNaddaf That worked. It seems that I don't fully understand the difference between application types. Will work on it. Thanks!